# iOS How to detect focus change between textfields in custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, focus, custom-keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard and i want to change my keyboard layout to adapt to the `UITextField` type (url, websearch, email) every time user change the focus between textfields.

For example:

- Beginning, user inputs in url textfield, my keyboard will show a dot button.
- After finished the editing in url textfield, user focus on email textfield, my keyboard will replace a dot button by @ button.

The question is how to catch this even in custom keyboard?

Comment: do you have your textfields in an interface builder? You can set the keyboard type straight in there.

Comment: @dirtydanee i know, i can detect keyboard type at the beginning, but when user switch to other textfield , i can't detect that event to make a change to my keyboard layout to adapt to new keyboard type.

Comment: do u have any sample code?

Comment: @engmahsa sample code? there's no need, i only need how to detect focus change event between textfields in custom keyboard. i can handle everything on my custom keyboard, but i need to catch focus change event.

Comment: If you have several text field you can devide them with tag ang define keyboard type for each one in delegate

Comment: Yes as @engmahsa said , you can use tags for textfields depending on the tag of the current textfield the respective keyboard will be shown